# How to install PyCharm on Ubuntu Mate (Raspberry Pi3)?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to install PyCharm on my Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu Mate.
But I do not figure out and understand the error message I get.

First I followed this tutorial :
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pycharm-on-ubuntu-18-04/

it was just about writing 
'''python 
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
'''

I received this error : snap "pycharm-community" is not available on stable for this architecture (armhf) but exists on other architectures (amd64).

Secondly I tried an other tutorial using Umake.
https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-pycharm-on-ubuntu-16-04/

I received this error : "Keyerror : 'armhf'".

What does it means? It is possible to install Pycharm on a raspberry running Ubuntu Mate?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You should perhaps ask this on the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: pycharm is not meant to be executed on ARM environment, plus raspberry pi is too weak to handle such tool. Try finding a way to execute pycharm on your local environment and setup a remote server to your raspberry pi so you can work on it without having it to run the whole IDE. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html